# Error initializing ssd1306 OLED connected to Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: i2c, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

What's going on? `i2c.scan()` returns [60] as it should:

```
from machine import Pin, I2C
import ssd1306

i2c = I2C(0, sda=Pin(0), scl=Pin(1), freq=400000)
oled=ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
    File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 110, in __init__
    File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 36, in __init__
    File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 73, in init_display
    File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 101, in show
    File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 119, in write_data
OSError: [Errno 5] EIO
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [pico_ssd1306](https://github.com/kevinmcaleer/pico_ssd1306/blob/master/ssd1306.py) driver and run the following code:

```py
from machine import Pin, I2C
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C

i2c = I2C(0,sda=Pin(16),scl=Pin(17),freq=40000)
oled = SSD1306_I2C(128,64,i2c)

oled.fill(0)
oled.text("Hello",0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

plz check your OLED is support I2C or SPI ? If its SPI mode use SSD1306_SPT.